# Why does the size of the ball change?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, kinematics, projectile

I am reading Head First Physics.

On **page 372** it states that the **size** of the ball changes. I have checked my previous notes, but I cannot understand why?

Here is a picture of the page:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> On page 372 it states that the size of the ball changes.

No, it says that the size of the ball’s velocity changes. It is a little weird to use the word size instead of magnitude, but it is talking about the velocity.

Comment: But what does it mean to change in size, does it mean speed? Does the size increase or decrease?

Comment: The "size" of the velocity is the speed. It is weird to use the word "size" to refer to velocity. It would be better to say "magnitude"

Answer (score 1):

It is not saying that **the size of the ball is changing**. It states that the **ball's velocity changes in size** which means that the magnitude of the velocity of the ball changes. This is true because there is an external force $mg$ on the ball in the vertically downward direction.

Hope it helps

Comment: But what does it mean to change in size, does it mean speed? Does the size increase or decrease?

Comment: @securityauditor by change in size , yes it means speed. When the ball is on its path to reach the highest point , the size or magnitude of the velocity in vertical direction decreases because of gravity but in its return journey the size or magnitude of the velocity increases ..